# Use macbook inbuilt microphone with audio going through mic-less earphones

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, audio, microphone, skype

I want to buy Sony Earphones for use with my MacBook Pro Mid-2014 edition. The earphones have no built in mic. Can my MacBook play audio through my earphones and use the inbuilt mac microphone at the same time e.g. during skype calls or will I have to unplug the earphones for 2 way communication?

I am using OS X 10.10

Comment: It's automatic. The computer will use inbuilt mic. The output will be your earphone and input will be inbuilt mic. No set up required.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you will be able to use your internal mic and headphones. A useful shortcut is option click on the speaker icon on the menu bar.

Comment: Do I need any configuration or its just `automatic`

Comment: No need to configure anything. However if you connect a headset, you can still force to use the internal mic.

Comment: how do I force it to use my internal mic while relaying the audio to my earphones?

Comment: From sound preferences or by option-clicking the speaker icon on the menu bar.